# How do you update a referenced document in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a reservation system of sorts using mongoose and nodejs. 
There are a list of hotels which have number of available rooms as a field. 
While creating a new booking for a customer, I want to update the number of available rooms in the hotel by reducing it by 1, for example.

Here's my code:

Hotel Model File:

```
var hotel: new mongoose.Schema{
name: String, 
availableRooms: {type: Number, default: 1}}
```

Booking Model File:

```
var booking: new mongoose.Schema{
userName: String,
hotelId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'hotel'}
}
```

Here's the post operation that I'm having trouble with:

```
api.route('/booking').post(function(req,res){
hotel.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.body.hotelId, availableRooms: {$gt: 0}},
availableRooms: -1, function(err){
if (err) throw err})
booking.create(req.body, function(err, confirmedBooking){
if (err) throw err;
res.json(confirmedBooking)
});
```

Postman shows this error:

ReferenceError: hotel is not defined

Comment: how are you including `Hotel` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code:

1. You might not have imported hotel schema in your node app(app.js/ server.js).
   The error from `postman` `hotel is undefined` is coming because of that.

If you have already imported, please check variable name, they are case sensitive, so check that too.

To import the hotel schema in your node app.:

```
var Hotel = require('path/to/hotel.js');
//OR
var Hotel = mongoose.model('Hotel');
```

Then try updating the document using `Hotel`, instead of `hotel`.

2. you cant `decrease` the value of a `field` like that, you need to use `$inc`.

Try this:

```
var hotelId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.body.hotelId);
// Dont forget to include mongoose in your app.js
Hotel.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: hotelId, availableRooms: {$gt: 0}
},{
    $inc : { availableRooms : -1 }
}, function(err){
    if (err) throw err
    else
    {
        booking.create(req.body, function(err, confirmedBooking){
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(confirmedBooking)
        });
    }
});
```

**Update** :  I have moved the section to creat new booking inside the callback of update function, so that new booking gets created only when it is successfully updated. It's better to use this way

Comment: Hey, I made the requisite changes that you suggested. The program is compiling. However, when I send a POST request through postman now, it does not connect to localhost. It throws a Cast to ObjectId failed for  value "req.body.hotelId" at path "_id" for model "hotel".

Comment: Can you do `console.log(req.body.hotelId)` and tell me what is coming?

Comment: Please make sure, `hotelId` is correctly passed in the POST request. Also, `id` should be `_id`, please have a look at updated answer.

Comment: So, basically, I've created different hotels using the same router in /hotel using a Post function. These have all created the different hotels. I just lifted one of the IDs and put it in a post function to create a booking. Without the update operation, it shows whatever I passed. With it, it throws the same error as earlier.

Comment: Which version of Mongoose are you running?

Comment: I'm running version "4.0.5"

Comment: Can you do `console.log(req.body.hotelId)` and tell me what is coming? I want to the result of this

Comment: Okay, I'm doing this without the update operation because mongoose won't allow it otherwise. This returns 588a50e441ecb01a0478ad8e 
This is exactly the same as the field hotelId passed in the req body.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. Also do you want to create new booking only if hotel updates??

Comment: Got it sorted out. The issue was referring to id as 'req.body.hotelId' and not req.body.hotelId. Guess postman can't resolve the single inverted commas.

Comment: Hey, I had another issue with the code. While trying to create a booking in a hotel with zero rooms, postman goes on to create the booking. Moreover, the number of available rooms doesn't go below 0. It just stays at 0.